# Doron Zeilberger's opinion 123

Tags: number-theory, examples-counterexamples

I recently came across [Doron Zeilberger's opinion 123](https://sites.math.rutgers.edu/%7Ezeilberg/Opinion123.html) where he writes (in 2012) that a corrigendum to Andrew Wiles's article proving Fermat Last Theorem was about to be published in Annals of Mathematics. According to Dr. Zeilberger's opinion 123, Wiles himself acknowledged that he had overlooked some cases, and after he fixed the argument we can now only conclude that there are at most three counterexamples to Fermat Last Theorem. I have not been able to find any subsequent information on the web about the corrigendum in Annals of Mathematics and I would be interest in knowing of any further development of this topic.

Comment: There are now formally verified, computer-checked proofs of FLT. The opinion is moot now.

Comment: And if the corrigendum did appear in Annals, why would Wiles be given the Abel Prize in 2016 for proving FLT? It would be common knowledge that there was still a gap in Wiles's proof, but that is not common knowledge now.

Comment: @ParclyTaxel where can I find this computer-checked proof of FLT?

Comment: I agree that we can safely assume that Wiles' proof is correct. Whether this (extremely complicated) proof was actually fully formalized is another story.

Comment: Contrary to some claims : No easier proof of this theorem has yet been found. We need the "big guns" Wiles used.

Comment: Thanks for the comments. I was not advocating in one direction or the other in the proof of FLT, and I was only asking for any information on any subsequent development from opinion No 123 of Dr. Zeilberger, who is a widely well-known and established mathematician who made important contribution to combinatorics.

Comment: @ParclyTaxel: I'm pretty sure the proof of FLT has *not* been formalized yet; see [here](https://proofassistants.stackexchange.com/questions/100/why-havent-all-of-the-hundred-greatest-theorems-been-formalized-yet), for example.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Look at the date of that opinion. -DZ

Comment: Thank you for the clarification Dr. Zeilberger, that opinion definitely fooled me. I now feel less bad about the downvotes, they are deserved after all....